# Separate elements and return in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to implement a Haskell function that takes a list of elements in the form of `(U "NAME", I "Item Name", INT_HERE)` and returns the "Item Name" part of each, I would like however to only return each distinct "Item name" once if it's repeated, I have already implemented the function `(dis :: Eq a => [a] -> [a])` that filters only distinct values in a list.

For example, for this input:

```
stackOverFlowFunction [(U "John" , I "GTX 1070", 5), 
                       (U "Ahmed" , I "Lenovo Y5070", 3), 
                       (U "Carole" , I "Honda Civic", 5), 
                       (U "Nada" , I "Honda Civic", 4),
                       (U "Ahmed" , I "GTX 1070", 1)]
```

It should return

```
[I "GTX 1070", I "Lenovo Y5070", I "Honda Civic"]
```

Comment: Great function! What have you tried?

Comment: stackOverFlowFunctionn :: Eq a => [(b,a,c)] -> [a]
stackOverFlowFunctionn  ((b,a,c):xs) = a

Comment: Got a unification would give infinite type error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after a slightly modified [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub):

```
data I = I String deriving (Show, Eq)
data U = U String deriving (Show, Eq)

nubI :: [(U, I, Int)] -> [I]
nubI = nub . map (\(_, i, _) -> i)
```

Which gives...

```
> nubI [(U "John" , I "GTX 1070", 5), (U "Ahmed" , I "Lenovo Y5070", 3), (U "Carole" , I "Honda Civic", 5), (U "Nada" , I "Honda Civic", 4),(U "Ahmed" , I "GTX 1070", 1)]
[I "GTX 1070",I "Lenovo Y5070",I "Honda Civic"]
```

Comment: This is perfect, didn't know about nub so now I don't need my distinct helper either, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your function takes a list, but only returns a *single* value. As-is, you need recursion to *add* the extracted value to the list of the rest of such values.

```
stackOverflowFunction [] = []
stackOverflowFunction ((b,a,c):xs) = a : stackOverflowFunction xs
```

However, this just duplicates the recursion scheme implemented by the `map` function:

```
extract :: (b, a, c) -> a
extract (_, a, _) = a

stackOverflowFunction :: [(b, a, c)] -> [a]
stackOverflowFunction xs = dis (map extract xs)
-- stackOverflowFunction xs = dis (map (\(_,a,_) -> a) xs)
```

With these,

```
>>> extract (U "John" , I "GTX 1070", 5)
I "GTX 1070"
>>> stackOverflowFunction [(U "John" , I "GTX 1070", 5), (U "Ahmed" , I "Lenovo Y5070", 3), (U "Carole" , I "Honda Civic", 5), (U "Nada" , I "Honda Civic", 4),(U "Ahmed" , I "GTX 1070", 1)]
>>> [I "GTX 1070",I "Lenovo Y5070",I "Honda Civic"]
```

(Presumed output of your `dis` function.)

Comment: ERROR - Undefined data constructor "I" on using this

Comment: Well, where is is supposed to come from? Your input implies it is already defined.

Comment: My bad forgot to include the declaration, the recursion approach works fine, many thanks